# Error when running StarFM

Tags: r, modis, landsat, fusion

I aim to make the fusion of Landsat and Modis using STARFM at [USDA StarFM](https://www.ars.usda.gov/research/software/download/?softwareid=432&modecode=80-42-05-10)

I tried to conduct this process in R, in which we call the software using this code:

> system2(command="./StarFM.exe",args="StarFM_config.txt", wait=TRUE)

However, this cannot run to produce the final results.

I also tried to run the software from Command Prompt as shown below:

> cd .\StarFM\source
>
> StarFM.exe

And got this result:

[image]

Can you help me to check, and run this software in R, especially to process Remote sensing data?

Comment: Not really a GIS question as this is a Windows 10 [DotNET .3.5] issue > Configure 16-bit Application Support in Windows 10 https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-16-bit-application-support-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

STARFM was designed for use in Linux only.
For window users, the solution is SARbian (https://eo-college.org/sarbian/).
The OS was adjusted with some RS-GIS Softwares already.
We even can install it on USB for "sandwich" running.

Comment: Not quite sure about this. That looks like a full blown OS based on Debian. Whereas the link OP has is for an .exe file, which is usually used with Windows.

Comment: I do not really understand much about OS, especially Debian. But, I know that SARbian is based on Debian. Moreover, I did run STARFM on SARbian. And it is successful.

Comment: Is there any other STARFM implented for Win 10? Running it in Linux is my last choice, because it takes some time to install and master Linux OS.